# Compiling Linux kernel for a router

Tags: compiling, linux-kernel, configuration, routing, bootable

I want to make an installable linux kernel that has routing enabled already. So anyone can install it on their machine, do some configuration as required, and machine will work fine for their routing needs. This is what I did so far.

1. Downloading and decompressing a vanilla linux kernel.
2. placing a ".config" file in that kernel directory.
3. Ready to make kernel....

I want to ask what options do I need to enable or disable in .config to make this a bootable software router (I don't need any other functionality)?

Note: I don't want to use any already built router, I want to create my own so I can manipulate and test it further.

Comment: A standard Linux-based OS is already able to route. You don't need a special configuration for that, except enabling packet forwarding. I may be wrong but I'd say that options you need in you .config depend more on your hardware than your specific routing needs.

Comment: I want it to be working on any x86/x64 hardware mainly. Other than that, do I need to set CONFIG_IP_FORWARD only? or should I enable/disable more parameters in .config file to make it work?
Default kernel (without changing Sysctl.conf) is not able to route IMHO. But I want to change it at compile time, so anyone who installs my package, does not need to change any settings (enabling/disabling anything).

Comment: If you just want a router, then yes, CONFIG_IP_FORWARD seems necessary as it allows you to have IP forwarding enabled by default. Then of course you need the driver for your network interfaces. Depending on what you want to do, you may need IPv6 stack or not. etc. etc.

Comment: A Linux kernel alone will not do this. You also need a userland to configure network interfaces, enable routing, set up the routing table, etc. You say you don't want to use an already built one, but you can use that as a *reference* to see how someone else did it. Then build your own from what you learn by looking at the work others have already done.

Comment: @lgeorget CONFIG_IP_FORWARD is no more there in kernel config for 3.12.14 at least. Any alternatives or any ideas?

Comment: No, sorry. :-/ Anyway, you should avoid double-posting. :-) Eventually someone will have this answer there: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123981/enabling-ip-forwarding-at-kernel-compile-time

Answer (score -1):

There is no simple `make` so "anyone can install it on their machine". What you may need to do is cross compile the kernel for the specific architecture. This will probably look something like this for an arm machine (which most routers you want to use might be) (note you will need an arm tool chain for the compiling, google around for that please)

`ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/path/to/arm/toolchain/bin make`

Then the bzImage will be inside of `arch/arm/boot` and tadah, get that onto a router you would like to use and have at it

Also possibly look up common configs from openwrt, they are the router guys when it comes to linux

Comment: The question was about the options necessary in the .config. Although your point is worth noting, you don't answer the OP's question.

Comment: ah, I guess I read it wrong. In his steps he had already made the .config and was ready to make. Then definitely look at openwrt's .config

Comment: OK, I know hardware architectures issue, I meant any x86/x64 architecture only.
And I don't want to use openwrt, click or anything pre-built as I mentioned in the question. Point is not using, but I want to make one.

Comment: something like this may work https://github.com/cozybit/openwrt_11s/blob/master/config_files/kernel.dot.config

Comment: Thanks @JacobMinshall It will hopefully help. I will read it now.