# Enabling IP forwarding at kernel compile time

Tags: kernel, compiling, linux-kernel, ip, forwarding

I am compiling a kernel for a router. I know a way to enable IP forwarding in an existing Linux system. At compile time, `CONFIG_IP_FORWARD` is said to do the same task.

I am configuring version 3.12.14 of the vanilla kernel using the GTK-based kernel configuration tool (`gconfig`). However, I can't see this option anywhere. Is there an alternate configuration option in recent kernels or am I missing something?

Comment: Simple question: why?

Comment: Simple answer: I need it for a project, A kernel, that is installed on a machine, does a lot other things than plain forwarding that I am configuring in my kernel. Forwarding seems to be a pain. Very little documentation is available for a lot of linux kernel features.

Comment: I meant why do you need it compiled into the kernel? To forward packets forwarding is not enough, you need also some iptables-rules.

Comment: iptables has nothing to do with that.  All you need are appropriate routing table entries.

Comment: iptables has to do with `ip_forward` setting, perhaps here is meant device/forwarding. However it is still not clear why it needs to be compiled into kernel. Is there a need to run a standalone kernel w/o any file system?

Comment: @bersch: There is, there is a reason. I am not going to explain my project here. Why is not important for answering this question.

Comment: I took a look at newer kernels, they seem do not have this flag. Normally you could just `echo CONFIG_IP_FORWARD=y >.config; make gconfig`; Anyways, if it is not there, then you simply `find /proc/sys|grep forward` to check if its compiled in.

Comment: I have not used gconfig but it should have a search; if there is nothing obvious try `/` (this is a standard *nix-ish short cut and works in menuconfig).  The searches work best if you use the option name (so `IP_FORWARD` will find it),  Note that options can have prerequisites (for this reason @bersch 's idea strikes me as a bad one) and if those are not selected, you won't see the option.  However, the info shown via search should tell you what the pre-reqs are.

Answer (score 5):

The Linux kernel source hasn't had the `CONFIG_IP_FORWARDING` option since the [2.0.x kernel series](https://lkml.org/lkml/1998/1/8/5). As far as I know, there is no compile time option anymore to enable IP forwarding by default for the built kernel.

Since the 2.1.x series, the correct way to enable IP forwarding for IPv4 has been with the [`net.ipv4.ip_forward`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt) [`sysctl`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sysctl) option.

Add the following line to `sysctl.conf` (or a file in `/etc/sysctl.d`):

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Then, have `sysctl` reload the configuration:

```
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

That said, if for some reason you need to configure the kernel so that setting the sysctl option (or the `/proc` equivalent) at boot time isn't needed, you could change the default value for the `sysctl` option directly in the kernel source tree*.

The *sysctl* table entry for `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` is initialized from a static structure defined in `net/ipv4/devinet.c`:

```
static struct ctl_table ctl_forward_entry[] = {
        {
                .procname       = "ip_forward",
                .data           = &ipv4_devconf.data[
                                        IPV4_DEVCONF_FORWARDING - 1],
                .maxlen         = sizeof(int),
                .mode           = 0644,
                .proc_handler   = devinet_sysctl_forward,
                .extra1         = &ipv4_devconf,
                .extra2         = &init_net,
        },
        { },
};
```

The `data` field is initialized to point to a entry in the integer array `data`, which is a field in the static `ipv4_devconf` structure. The entry is identified by the `IPV4_DEVCONF_FORWARDING` enumerated value defined in `include/uapi/linux/ip.h`. The `data` array contained in the structure is only partially initialized, omitting the `IPV4_DEVCONF_FORWARDING` entry. Since the structure has static storage, all integral type members are initialized to zero. Hence, to set the data field for the `ip_forward` *sysctl* table entry, and the recorded default value, we need to initialize `ipv4_devconf.data[IPV4_DEVCONF_FORWARD - 1]` and the corresponding field in the `ipv4_devconf_dflt` structure to `1`. This can be achieved with the following patch:

```
diff --git a/net/ipv4/devinet.c b/net/ipv4/devinet.c
index bdbf68b..91fe073 100644
--- a/net/ipv4/devinet.c
+++ b/net/ipv4/devinet.c
@@ -69,6 +69,7 @@

 static struct ipv4_devconf ipv4_devconf = {
        .data = {
+               [IPV4_DEVCONF_FORWARDING - 1] = 1,
                [IPV4_DEVCONF_ACCEPT_REDIRECTS - 1] = 1,
                [IPV4_DEVCONF_SEND_REDIRECTS - 1] = 1,
                [IPV4_DEVCONF_SECURE_REDIRECTS - 1] = 1,
@@ -80,6 +81,7 @@ static struct ipv4_devconf ipv4_devconf = {

 static struct ipv4_devconf ipv4_devconf_dflt = {
        .data = {
+               [IPV4_DEVCONF_FORWARDING - 1] = 1,
                [IPV4_DEVCONF_ACCEPT_REDIRECTS - 1] = 1,
                [IPV4_DEVCONF_SEND_REDIRECTS - 1] = 1,
                [IPV4_DEVCONF_SECURE_REDIRECTS - 1] = 1,
```

<sub>* **Disclaimer:** I'm no expert in Linux networking internals, so it's entirely possible that the method described here misses some initializations normally performed by the `devinet_sysctl_forward()` when forwarding is normally enabled via `sysctl`, so proceed with care. The above patch seems to work against kernel version 3.14 to the extent that `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` indeed indicates forwarding to be enabled by default, without configuration via `sysctl`. As far as I see, 3.12.14 does not seem to differ with regards to the *sysctl* entry initialization. I included the patch in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY.</sub>

Comment: So it changed since 2.1.x.... OK thanks :) And yes I know `sysctl.conf` method already.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question: how to configure the kernel so that running `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` at boot time (or the `/proc` equivalent) isn't needed.

Comment: @Gilles Fair enough, although it seemed to me that _"there is no such compile time option anymore_" would be an acceptable answer. As far as I know, the only way to achieve this would be to modify the kernel source. I updated to answer with information about how the particular _sysctl_ option is initialized, if someone would want to IP forwarding enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any solution for enabling it statically (and in at least recent kernels there's no `CONFIG_IP_FORWARD` - just `grep`ed the source).

From a security perspective this doesn't seem to be a good idea anyways, since in many cases you might to configure some other things before enabling forwarding (filtering rules, QoS rules, [more exact] routing rules, for example).

Comment: I know there is no CONFIG_IP_FORWARD now, that's what I said. Question is if this feature is enabled by some other parameter at compile time or it is not possible at all now.

Comment: What I wanted to say was: As far as I can see, there's not.

Answer (score -1):

IP forwarding is a core functionality of the network code in Linux. That's why there is no configuration variable for it.

Comment: There used to be a variable for that, anyway, probably a start-up script has to be written instead. Do you know of a way/interface/API to insert routing table entries? Not static, but dynamic ones.

Comment: "ip" from the iproute2 package does what you need,  i.e. "ip -6 route add 2001:db8:0:cafe::/64 dev enp1s2" etc. http://www.policyrouting.org/iproute2.doc.html has a very readable guide to "ip".

Comment: You didn't get the question.  Of course it's core functionality, but it's disabled after startup, so your computer does not act as a router if not excplicitly told to.